# CameraManager.TorchCallback throws ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to create widget with several features, one of them is flashlight.

I'm using new `Camera2` api but can't really get it working.

I created custom `CameraManager.TorchCallback` class to handle torch on/off callbacks but `constructor` call throws `ClassNotFound` exception:

> Didn't find class "md50ef6a3f50a79fbeb48e8252e4750d416.FlashLightCallback" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.arsena.rooting-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.arsena.rooting-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Here is the partial source of my `appWidget`:

```
public class RootWidgets : AppWidgetProvider, IFlashLightStateListener
{
    Context _context;

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (/* some condition */)
        {
            _context = context;
            UpdateWidget(context);
            return;
        }
    }

    #region IFlashLightStateListener implementation

    bool _flashLightEnabled;
    public bool IsFlashLightEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _flashLightEnabled;
        }

        set
        {
            _flashLightEnabled = value;
            UpdateWidget(_context);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private void UpdateWidget(Context context)
    {
        // some actions...

        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.CameraService);
        var callBack = new FlashLightCallback(this);

        cameraManager.RegisterTorchCallback(callBack, null);

        // some actions...
    }
}
```

`FlashLightCallback` class:

```
 public class FlashLightCallback : CameraManager.TorchCallback
{
    IFlashLightStateListener _fListener;
    Context _context;

    public FlashLightCallback(IFlashLightStateListener flashStateListener) // here comes exception
    {
        _fListener = flashStateListener;
    }

    public override void OnTorchModeChanged(string cameraId, bool enabled)
    {
        base.OnTorchModeChanged(cameraId, enabled);

        _fListener.IsFlashLightEnabled = enabled;
    }
}

public interface IFlashLightStateListener
{
    bool IsFlashLightEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Full exception stack trace:

```
    [flashlight] Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md50ef6a3f50a79fbeb48e8252e4750d416.FlashLightCallback" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.arsena.rooting-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.arsena.rooting-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

[flashlight]   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+Types.FindClass (System.String classname) [0x00132] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.Types.cs:66 
[flashlight]   at Java.Interop.JniType..ctor (System.String classname) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniType.cs:30 
[flashlight]   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods..ctor (System.Type declaringType) [0x0006a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.cs:25 
[flashlight]   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.GetConstructorsForType (System.Type declaringType) [0x0003b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.cs:80 
[flashlight]   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.StartCreateInstance (System.String constructorSignature, System.Type declaringType, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00044] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.cs:111 
[flashlight]   at Android.Hardware.Camera2.CameraManager+TorchCallback..ctor () [0x00022] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Hardware.Camera2.CameraManager.cs:175 
[flashlight]   at Rooting.FlashLightCallback..ctor (IFlashLightStateListener flashStateListener) [0x00000] in /Users/imac/Projects/Rooting/Rooting/FlashLightCallback.cs:12 
[flashlight]   at Rooting.RootWidget.UpdateWidget (Android.Content.Context context) [0x001fe] in /Users/imac/Projects/Rooting/Rooting/RootWidget.cs:173 

[flashlight]   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
[flashlight] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md50ef6a3f50a79fbeb48e8252e4750d416.FlashLightCallback" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.arsena.rooting-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.arsena.rooting-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
[flashlight]    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
[flashlight]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
[flashlight]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
[flashlight]    at md50ef6a3f50a79fbeb48e8252e4750d416.RootWidget.n_onReceive(Native Method)
[flashlight]    at md50ef6a3f50a79fbeb48e8252e4750d416.RootWidget.onReceive(RootWidget.java:29)
[flashlight]    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3022)
[flashlight]    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:179)
[flashlight]    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1539)
[flashlight]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
[flashlight]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
[flashlight]    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
[flashlight]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[flashlight]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
[flashlight]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
[flashlight]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
[flashlight]    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: md50ef6a3f50a79fbeb48e8252e4750d416.FlashLightCallback
[flashlight]        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
[flashlight]        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
[flashlight]        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
[flashlight]        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
[flashlight]        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
[flashlight]        ... 14 more
[flashlight]    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: md50ef6a3f50a79fbeb48e8252e4750d416.FlashLightCallback
[flashlight]        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
[flashlight]        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
[flashlight]        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
[flashlight]        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.jav
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Use a [sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jeatv1xlewozu6i/TorchCallbackSample.zip?dl=0) to replicate exception.

Comment: Can you create a small sample project and upload it to dropbox and provide the link here? Ideally it's saying this class is not being found in your main dexlist. Are you using Multidex? More investigation would be possible with a sample project.

Comment: Sure, I'll upload it soon.
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @JonDouglas I've uploaded a sample, check it out.

Comment: Can you also add replication steps? After hitting the flash button of your widget I get a different exception.

https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/f873475222f821ddc12a1e8f90d71e70

Comment: As a secondary comment, the flash widget seems to work just fine on my Motorola Nexus 6 running API 23. However it looks like you have a memory leak within it. The prior comment was done on an emulator without a camera.